# Parameter set cannot be resolved with mutually exclusive non default parameters

Tags: powershell

Following is full param block signature, I tried almost every possible solution that I'm aware of such as
adding `Mandatory` to `File` and `Thumbprint` parameters sets, removing default parameter set etc, none of which works.

Problem description and desired functionality is this:

`Domain` parameter is always required while `File` and `ThumbPrint` are optional but mutually exclusive.

I run this test as follows:

```
.\Set-WinRM* -Domain VM-PRO
```

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

```
function Set-WinRM
{
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false, DefaultParameterSetName = "None")]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet("HTTP", "HTTPS", "Any")]
    [string] $Protocol = "HTTPS",

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Alias("ComputerName", "CN")]
    [string] $Domain,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "File")]
    [string] $CertFile,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "ThumbPrint")]
    [string] $CertThumbPrint,

    [Parameter()]
    [switch] $SkipTestConnection,

    [Parameter()]
    [switch] $ShowConfig
    )
}
```

**EDIT:**

I never use dynamic parameters, if this can't be done normally maybe you can provide an example on how to define them in this example, that would be great.

Comment: The code you have works perfectly for me. For sanity, can you try adding `Function Set-WinRM { your-code-here }` around it and try it that way?

Comment: Wait, this isn't a function it's script and it indeed works! I'll have to see what's wrong and update my post soon! thank you!

Comment: I voted to close my question because it serves no purpose for anyone to learn anything from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy and pasted your code into Powershell ISE, and added `echo $domain` to the end to test the parameter. It returns the value normally, without errors:

[image]

I don't see any issues with your parameter block, which leads me to believe something else is at fault. If you type out `.\Set-WinRM.ps1 -Do`, or `Set-WinRM -Do` can you tab-complete it successfully? If you run `Set-WinRM` without parameters at all, does it prompt you for `Domain:`?

I would only expect to see that error if you had additional parameter sets with `$domain` doing different things, or maybe if a module you have loaded has the `Set-WinRM` command and it's taking precedence. Try `Get-Command Set-WinRM` and make sure the `CommandType` is Function and the `Source` is blank.

Comment: I figured out problem in my case was that my script called another script which was producing the actual problem! Now the reason why didn't I figure out the issue is because error message didn't tell me it's inner script that is causing problem! thank you, without your input I would never discover this lol. (both scripts have same params)